# Super weird Git problem, expected committer name

Tags: git

Had a bug last week and somehow my comitter last name got changed from "Menzner" to "Menzer" and it won't let me push anymore.  I've tried every combination of commands to try to reset it, but nothing works.  Yes, I've already tried git config --global user.name etc etc as well as some amend commands, but this error still shows.  When I run git config --list, I can even see that my name and email have correctly updated to "Menzner" yet I still get this error when I push.  Any advice?  This is a weird one.
[image]

(Like I said I've already tried most git config commands)

Comment: I would check each of the [configuration scopes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#SCOPES) to see if any of your `gitconfig` files still have the old email

Comment: Who is the committer of `a72c8ba12`?  You probably need to edit that commit to fix the committer.

Comment: "somehow my comitter last name got changed from "Menzner" to "Menzer"" Well it didn't happen by magic. Do a global search of your hard drive for "Menzer".

Comment: Once a commit is created, it is never changed again. If you need to change the name of commits before pushing, you must create new commits with the correct name and push those instead.